# How can I retrieve values from multiple FormControl instances in Angular using RxJS?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I subscribe to `filter1`, `filter2`, and `filter3`, all of which are `FormControl` instances. Whenever at least one of them changes, I want to retrieve the values of all three. Initially, I attempted to use `combineLatest`, but I noticed that it emits only when all of them have emitted values. Then, I tried using `merge`, but encountered an issue where it only returned the field that changed.

So, how can I obtain an object `{ filter1, filter2, filter3 }` using RxJS?

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';
import { FormControl, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { merge } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
console.clear();

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, CommonModule],
  template: `
 <input [formControl]="filter1">
 <input [formControl]="filter2">
 <input [formControl]="filter3">
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';

  filter1 = new FormControl();
  filter2 = new FormControl();
  filter3 = new FormControl();

  constructor() {
    merge(
      this.filter1.valueChanges.pipe(map(value => ({ filter1: value }))),
      this.filter2.valueChanges.pipe(map(value => ({ filter2: value }))),
      this.filter3.valueChanges.pipe(map(value => ({ filter3: value })))
    ).subscribe((x) => {
      console.log(x);
    });
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

Please note that I don't want to use `formGroup` and I want to know how to do it without use `formGroup`.

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-cmh7oa?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

Comment: I’m curious why you don’t want to use formGroup. This is the easiest way to get an observable that emits whenever any of the fields change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The operator `combineLatest` is the correct approach, but you need to use the `startWith` operator for each observable first to provide an initial value. If you don't want the initial value with all filters empty, you can also pipe the result of `combineLatest` through `skip(1)`.

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { startWith, combineLatest } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ReactiveFormsModule],
  template: `
    <input [formControl]="filter1" />
    <input [formControl]="filter2" />
    <input [formControl]="filter3" />
  `,
})
export class AppComponent {
  filter1 = new FormControl();
  filter2 = new FormControl();
  filter3 = new FormControl();

  constructor() {
    combineLatest({
      filter1: this.filter1.valueChanges.pipe(startWith('')),
      filter2: this.filter2.valueChanges.pipe(startWith('')),
      filter3: this.filter3.valueChanges.pipe(startWith('')),
    }).subscribe((x) => {
      console.log(x);
    });
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(AppComponent);
```